# configuring error messages in flex application

Tags: apache-flex

I'm trying to create a Flex based internet application with an EJB layer in the server. This layer provides the XML used by the flex application. It uses the Cairngorm architecture. Currently, on an error I call the handler function defined in all the command files. How can I centralize this?

My idea is to create a XML file that contains all the error messages and the types of error message eg:- Warning, Error etc. In the error handler, I will call the error handling function and pass a unique id which in turn will display the error message defined in the xml config file. Do I need to load this XML file in the Model layer of the application itself and store them as say global variables?

Please suggest me ideas on overriding the Alert box so that I can create Warning alert, Error alert etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the xml file when the app loads, and store the messages on a model. When you need to fire off an error message, you can fire the appropriate event, and you can have a command that pulls the right one from the model and displays it. Alert is definitely the way to go if you want to have a command open a window.

The better (but harder) option is to have a view that binds to a model, which model has a property like "hasError" and "errorMessage", so if hasError gets set to true, the view opens a custom popup.

Comment: Well, I'm loading the XML as an object and storing in the model. Then trigger it based on an 'error_id'.

Answer (score 0):

TitleWindow is not good enough?